# System monitor detecting load averages higher in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, cpu-load

In 11.10 my load averages stayed around .06.I ve been on 12.04 precise for 3 days now and have noticed my load averages stay around 1.06 at all times.Can someone tell me what is going on?I was told that 12.04 precise was faster and efficient.Anyone else experiencing this issue?**update**I woke up this morning noticing my hdd was being accessed.I woke my computer and checked system monitor.My load averages were around 1.46 so it seems to be getting worse.This is the highest so far.I m running a quad core but I think at idle I should be like it was in 11.10,0.06.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone tell me what is going on?

Something is using more CPU.

That's about all anybody can say from what you've posted. I'd suggest you install `htop` and watch it in a terminal for a few minutes or use something like this for instant (if inaccurate) gratification:

```
ps aux | sort -r -k3 | head -11
```

That should give you some sort of idea what's nomming on the CPU.

From there you'll likely want to file a bug on Launchpad.net.

Comment: I had htop already installed.Everything in hyop seems to be running like it did in 11.10 with compiz in consuming more than others but the same behavior as in 11.10.I just reset unity and still getting higher loads before setting my desktop cube back up.I noticed that even with compiz features added or not 12.04 consumes,to me,extremely high loads.My display is also showing laptop when I am on a desktop.I dont know if this is connected but I have filed a bug as I keep researching and eliminating things.I am also running an ati hd6450 with fglrx.

Comment: When I upgraded from 11.10 everything went smooth but is it good practice to reinstall the graphics card driver after each upgrade ?Could the driver be the culprit ?I know I had a horrible time installing it when I installed this card in 11.10.I was met with just a purple screen.I just seem to think due to the display here reading my desktop as a laptop and high load averages it might have to deal with my graphics card driver

Comment: Just checked it out.This bug has already been reported

Answer (score 0):

Same to me, powertop shows:

100,0%                      Device         Códec de audio hwC0D0: Analog Devices

If this is your problem, you have some info here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/powertop/+bug/536631

But it doesn't help, and it seems the bug has closed???
http://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg3557916.html